# GET querystring in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-string

I need to edit a node.js app GET a querystring, without (i) using Express or any other modules and (ii) creating a server in addition to the one which already exists.

I want to pass ?id=helloworld into the variable id.

How would I do this?

Comment: If you google `"nodejs querystring"` the first result is a link to the docs about the native [`querystring` module](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the native `querystring` module to parse query strings.

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var str = req.url.split('?')[1];
  qs.parse(str);
});
```

Parsing query strings will return results in an object:

```
qs.parse('foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge')
// returns
{ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' }
```

You can also find the source of the module [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/querystring.js).

Comment: You will need to get pass only what is after the `?`, more like `qs.parse(req.url.split('?')[1])`

Comment: Thanks! How would I then write an if function for when foo=bar in the querystring?

Comment: `var result = qs.parse('foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge'); if (result.foo == 'bar') {}` is how you'd do that.